# Does examiner's own PhD outcome influence decision?

Tags: thesis, reference-request, thesis-committee, assessment

PhD examination outcomes, depending on country/university, may include unconditional pass, pass subject to minor or major corrections, and resubmission among others.

Is there any evidence or analysis (in any country) on whether an examiner's decision can in some way be influenced by their own PhD outcomes?

For instance, is an academic who himself/herself got a lower PhD outcome, e.g., major correction or resubmission, more likely to give lower outcomes when acting as an examiner?

Comment: I doubt that there is any significant data to show one way or the other...

Comment: I'm curious to know where you think this might be an issue. In my experience, if a candidate didn't do well in the defense, they were just given some ideas about what they needed to do to improve the work or presentation. There was no record left until success was obtained or the candidate gave up. Minor corrections, especially were treated as more of a clerical issue than substantial. Moreover, we treated it as the advisors responsibility not to let bad things happen.

Comment: @Buffy I'm curious to know how your comment relates to the question. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Orion, the first sentence is my puzzlement. The rest is why it is a puzzlement. With clarification, an answer might be provided, but I wouldn't know how to approach it without more from the OP.

Comment: @Buffy I think you misunderstood the question. It is about factors related to examiners rather than the student or the student's work.

Comment: Which question are you asking? Limit it to one clear question...

Comment: @SolarMike There is one clear question: **Is there any evidence or analysis (in any country) on whether an examiner's decision can in some way be influenced by their own PhD outcomes?**

Comment: What about the last para then...

Comment: @SolarMike This is an explanation of the question, I guess.